# How to get data from a class inside a class with same names but different data?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

Im trying to pull the data of my DnD characters stats (Strength, Dexterity, Wisdom, etc.) and print the number. Everything I've tried so far doesn't pull any data and prints null. https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/11196319

I've tried

```
doc.select("ct-ability-summary__label");

doc.select("ct-ability-summary__label").first();

doc.select("div[class=ct-ability-summary__primary:eq(0)]");

List<String> Stats = new ArrayList<>();
for( Element element : doc.select("div[class=ct-ability-summary__primary]") )
        {
            Stats.add(element.text());
        }


<div class="ct-quick-info__abilities">
    <div class="ct-quick-info__ability">
        <div class=" ct-ability-summary">
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__heading">...</div>
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__primary">10</div>
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__secondary">...</div>
    <div class="ct-quick-info__ability">
        <div class=" ct-ability-summary">
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__heading">...</div>
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__primary">13</div>
            <div class="ct-ability-summary__secondary">...</div>
```

im trying to pull the data from the  and have it print out. so in this case i want the 10 and 13 to be printed. it can be added to a list/array or individual strings. as long as it gets the data to be available to print. if those two can work id assume i can get the other 4 to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit this page the first thing you see is empty page with loading spinner:
[image]

That's always a sign that some additional data is fetched by JavaScript and dynamically added into page (DOM). Jsoup can't execute JavaScript and that's why your selection returns null. 
You can use browser's debugger to check what's loaded:

[image]

You can see the data is stored as JSON and can be directly accessed using this URL:
https://www.dndbeyond.com/character/11196319/json

Unfortunately Jsoup can't parse JSON so you'll have to use some other library. Also note this page performs some calculations and not everything you see is noted directly in this JSON. For example if you format it you can see you have some stats:

```
stats: [
{
id: 1,
name: null,
value: 10},
{
id: 2,
name: null,
value: 13},
{
id: 3,
name: null,
value: 14},
{
id: 4,
name: null,
value: 15},
{
id: 5,
name: null,
value: 12},
{
id: 6,
name: null,
value: 12}
],
```

Something seems wrong because your intelligence is not 15 but 16 and that's because you have racial bonus +1 and that value is stored somewhere else. It may be complicated to find out how these stats influence each other.

So to make sure you have the correct final values instead of base I recommend to drop Jsoup approach with parsing JSON and use Selenium Webdriver instead as it's able to get the exact values you see because it executes JavaScript.